# Shielding an RF module from noise

Tags: rf, noise, interference, nrf24l01

I feel like a fool. As seen in the image below, the nRF module is right next to the VIN terminal. When I powered this up, I was able to communicate with the nrf module via SPI but it wouldn't receive or transmit data. I then powered the board via a seperate 3.3V supply and then the RF module worked. This led me to believe that the RF module was swamped with noise from the VIN cable. It never struck me that this wouldn't work since an earlier version of the board worked fine in the same layout. Since this is now a made board, not many modifications are possible. How do I shield the RF module from the noise or how do shield the VIN terminal so that it does not affect the RF module?

[image]

Comment: What is that Vin? 230 VAC or something else? Where is the voltage regulator? Is the voltage cable shielded (doesn't look like)?

Comment: @Lundin Its 12V DC. Its coming from an Meanwell SMPS a little distance away.

Comment: Ok that doesn't sound all that evil then, if it had been 230V then I would have called it unsalvagable. I'm more concerned about the stepper motor drivers nearby though. Is the motor primary side is sitting right next to the RF module? What are the black square parts next to the dip-switch? Relays, photocouplers, voltage regulators?

Comment: The components immediate next to the RF module are the step and dir signals coming from the MCU via the photocouplers. The stepper motor connectors are the the ones you see on the right most edge of the image above. The two black square parts are the current sense resistors. The DPAK part next to the two caps is the reverse protection device and the three photocouplers are next to it.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the RF module location near the heat sink.

It could be noise.

It could also be a noisy +3v3 power supply to the module, or heavy current from the stepper driver lifting the GND at the module, thus changing its logic threshold and/or latching it up or crashing its logic chip.

It's on a mezzanine connector, so you can try various approaches to do a differential diagnosis, isolate a cause:

Put a longer connector.

Put a cable between the board and the module and move it around.

Cut the GND and +3V3 from the cable and connect them to GND and 3V3 close to the micro so it uses the same references as the micro that it's talking to.

Measure noise between GND at your micro, and GND at the RF module, also noise between +3V3/GND on the module.

Solder a big decoupling cap on the module.

Etc.

You may find that is is not about location, but a grounding problem, or something else.

If it really is a location problem, and the module works perfectly if you put it at the end of a ribbon cable further away from the stepper driver and 12V input, then this is your fix, and you can ship your board, and brag about how you added that feature "to let the user place the RF module where it gets best reception".

Comment: I had placed a 3v3 and gnd connectors near the micro since I figured they may come in handy at some point. When I disconnect the 12VDC and power the board using a seperate 3v3 supply, the module works flawlessly. There is a footprint between the mezzanine connector and the end of the board for an SMD version of the module. I will try that as well. And I like the ribbon cable idea :)

Comment: OK. So when you apply +12V it stops working. Is it the power supply? (try a bunch of supplies, maybe a linear bench PSU). But maybe it is something on your board that is powered by 12V and generates noise, or pollutes the ground, so when there is no 12V, it stays quiet, and the power supply is not guilty...

Comment: @electrophile You really ought to measure the lines with a scope, if you have conducted noise you'll pick it up then. Getting rid of conducted noise is much easier than radiated/radio-related.

Answer (score 0):

Well... you really ought to move that radio far away from its current location, but I guess you already figured out as much :) I'm not convinced that these cheap radio modules have decent EMC characteristics to begin with though. The problems may be located on the RF module itself.

In the realm of desperate patches, here are various things you can attempt:

- One easy patch you can do is to switch the THR socket strip for a right angle one pointing towards that yellow switch/encoder. Then mount the module so that it points straight up with the crystal facing the switch/encoder.

  Hopefully the board has a proper ground plane in one layer that will shield a bit. This should help with radiated susceptibility in case the antenna is picking up noise.
- Ideally shield the radio as much as possible from the rest of the board, which in a professional solution would mean metal screens soldered to the RF board. Metal tape, foam and similar rarely works well. All of such desperate measures may interfere with the ob-board antenna too... an external antenna would have been much better but I take it that's not an option.
- As for conducted susceptibility, clock the SPI bus as slow as you can possible manage. SPI is not ideal for EMC and might as well be one of the culprits if you run it at several MHz. Fiddling around will slow control and/or small RC filters might improve it somewhat. If you get conducted noise then you'll be able to measure it with a scope on the SPI lines.
- Put a ferrite bead on the supply cable and switch to a shielded version. Preferably ground the shield on the supply side.

Comment: The board does have a solid GND plane and can't use an external antenna. However, as mentioned in the comment for the above answer, there is a footprint for an SMD version of the module. I will try that as well. Using a right angle connector and clocking slower SPI are good ideas. I will try that.

Comment: A quick update: tried the horizontal right angle socket and that did not work. Neither did using the same version of the module. Have not tried the ferrite bead yet.

Comment: @electrophile Again: have you verified if it's conducted or radiated EMI? You need to start there. Also, it might be the radio design which is the true culprit, in which case the solution is not to use a cheap hobbyist radio.